# Jquery help with matching

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with my code. It is not the issue. It is just good to have feature. currently if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/6yuuu/ and click on one of the links, so if this link has children links, then it shows all links under the parent(all levels).

This is because I use matching from the beggining of the string

```
if($href_sub.toLowerCase().indexOf($href.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
        }
```

How do I write function that is shows only one level down at a time. (so when I click "Reding GLE's" it displays only: " 1.2.1", "1.4.2", "2.2.1", "2.4.1", "2.4.2", "2.6.1" and when I click on one of those link it shows next children of the element.

It will probably require some regex matching?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you're overcomplicating something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML seems invalid for what you're trying to do. Your `ul` elements should be nested within one another rather that writing `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

```
<ul>
    <li><a /></li>
    <li><a />
        <ul>
            <li><a /></li>
            <li><a /></li>
            <li><a />
                <ul>
                    <li><a /></li>
```

which would make your jQuery that much more simple

```
$("#taxonomylist a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next("ul").children().slideToggle();
});
```

---

I do realize that some times changing things is not an option. Here is how you would do this using what you have:

```
$('#taxonomylist ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var count = url.split("/").length;
    $("#taxonomylist ul li a[href^='" + url + "']").each(function() {
        var $href_sub = $(this).attr("href");
        if(count + 1 == $href_sub.split("/").length)
        {
            $(this).parent().css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

This makes the assumption that everything 1 level lower will have 1 more `/`

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6yuuu/3/

Comment: Totally made my day. I really thought that I cannot change html, since it was generated by some crzy php, by it works very well with this html markup change. Thanks a lot.